# Add/remove programs in Windows XP with Python script

Tags: python, windows, system, administration

I would like to add add/programs like adobe acrobat reader and other application in windows XP using Python script. Kindly looking for some help.

Thanks in advance!

Everest.

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing or uninstalling?

#### Installing:

Easy way: `subprocess.Popen` the installer.

Nearly-as-easy way: `subprocess.Popen` the installer, with some Windows hackery so that the user doesn't have to click anything.

#### Uninstalling:

As above.

Hard way: work out the files changed on the computer and revert them manually.

Comment: Thank you for very much for the quick reply and tip. I am a newbie in python and basically do windows sysadmin tasks and sometimes write batch script. However i am trying to learn python by implementing the scripts in windows tasks. The actual task i want to do is a follows:

To remove acrobat reader or acrobat standard version and install acrobat professional.

I also have to remove SAP client application from the machine and be able to run another SAP install.cmd file which then installs an updated version of SAP.could your or someone post me a more or less complete working script?
Thanks