# Uninstall software from your computer using Python?

Tags: python, uninstallation

I am looking for a script that will remove a program from my computer (specifically LogMeIn Hamachi), and then re-install there after. (using python)

I have no idea where to start!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599213/add-remove-programs-in-windows-xp-with-python-script

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did, wish I could delete this question, it is kinda dumb.